# Mathematical Analysis Sequence and Textbook Recommendation

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, measure-theory

For a student of high school mathematical background with undergraduate studies in mathematics, what should be the sequence of courses and textbooks followed in order to understand mathematical analysis properly, starting from real analysis.

Comment: Try baby Rudin, then adult Rudin.

Comment: @MoisheKohan wherever I’ve looked baby rudin is generally not recommended for self study, so would it be fine for one to start with baby rudin?

Comment: Actually, you will see many interesting purposes to "analysis" if you study complex analysis for a year or two before worrying about the gauntlet of "real analysis", which is in many regards not so happy. Complex analysis is very happy, and has many amazing, unexpected applications to other things. In contrast, "introductory real analysis" all-too-easily slips into a sort of paranoia about whether what seems obviously/intuitively true is true at all... because there are crazy pathological possibilities... um, which do not actually manifest in practice... but... A matter of taste, I guess.

Comment: ... and in complex analysis, many good things _are_ true, which seem "too good to be true"! And these entail some too-good-to-be-true things throughout mathematics. Much more encouraging and useful than "worry".

Comment: @paulgarrett How should I go about studying complex analysis and then transition to Real analysis?

Comment: @brongulus I self studied baby Rudin, it was fine for me.

Comment: I’m also a high school student. And my math teacher recommends me to read Elementary analysis: theory of calculus by Kenneth Ross. I think it is fine

Comment: @Kevin.S Ross takes too much of an discursive approach, but yes it’s a good book.

Comment: Konrad Knopp's four little books on complex analysis (and translated to English), are very inexpensive, and are optimistic. Ahlors' classic text on complex analysis is quite nice, but insanely expensive, and a bit archaic.  I do tend to endorse my own notes on complex analysis, which were made for our intro grad course here, and with an eye to interesting applications to ... mathematics. For example, number theory. The grim concerns of "real analysis" simply do not enter... though, yes, perhaps, eventually, such concerns should be addressed. But not without knowing the positive things...

Comment: @paulgarrett thank you for elaborating, your page has a plethora of wonderful information and notes and I’ll surely check out the books you mentioned. But if you could address the grim concerns of real analysis too, that’d be a delight :) since I plan on jumping in the field soon enough...

Comment: *could address the grim concerns of real analysis too* --- Try [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=recommendation+real+analysis+site:math.stackexchange.com&filter=0).

Comment: Ross is a thinned down version of baby Rudin. I did not say "use baby Rudin" but "try it." I would recommend it for self-study for a strong student, but I have no idea how strong you are, which is why you should talk to somebody who actually knows you rather than some strangers from stack exchange.  This is why "Seeking personal advice" is one reason to close MSE questions.